# Opensuse default color theme from 13.1 in 13.2?

Tags: kde, opensuse, theme

Is there a straight way to setup the old "*default*" color theme (the one from 13.1) in 13.2 ?

The "*default*" color theme has changed. The problem is that i've started a wiki using some *ksnap-shots* of a software under 13.1, now I'm under 13.2, i don't have my 13.1 setup anymore and i'd like to keep the *ksnap-shots* look homogeneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `KDE System Settings > Application Appearence > Colours`, on the `Scheme` tab select `openSUSE` and click in `Save Scheme` and give a new name, such as "openSUSE-Green". 
Now select "openSUSE-Green" on the list and click on the tab `Colours`, there you need to change the colour of the following items, put the according colour in the `HTML` code area, so just copy and past it in yours and click ok:

`Window Background #D5D1CF`

`Button Background #CFCCC9`

`Selection Background #83AF77`

`Selection Inactive Text #B5EFAC`

`Focus Decoration #5D992D`

`Hover Decoration #6F9926`

`Tooltip Background #1C2122`

`Active Titlebar #83AF77`

`Active Titlebar Secondary #83AF77`

`Innactive Titlebar #D5D1CF`

`Innactive Titlebar Secondary #D5D1CF`